# How to reduce the record script using 'HTTP proxy server' in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

[image][image]If record any webpage, my jmeter gets more number of http request. Even though I exclude some files like `.js`, `.png` and `ect`. Is there any possibility to reduce recorded script?

Comment: Show us the requests it recorded and tell exactly what else do you wanna remove from recording?

Comment: Jmeter will only exclude which you will ask it to exclude. Do you have any specific requirement that which requests you donot want to see here? any specific pattern ?

Comment: This is simply login into a account, here http proxy server capture more than 100 http request. Is there any possible to reduce unwanted http request? any plugin, tools available for to reduce http request.

Comment: You can define the type of requests (js/gif/swf/ftp) that you want to exclude in JMeter recorder. Other than that you can manually delete the unwanted requests at end of recording.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch "Grouping" to `Store 1st sampler of each group only`.

[image: Proxy Grouping]

As per [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder):

> Store 1st sampler of each group only: only the first request in each group will be recorded. The "Follow Redirects" and "Retrieve All Embedded Resources..." flags will be turned on in those samplers.

This is what you should be normally doing and this is what real browsers do. Make sure you add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) during the test as real browsers download all these "embedded resources", but do it only once. If you will be downloading them on each iteration of every single thread - it won't be a realistic load model.

See [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743654-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article for more recommendations on how to make your tests look more real.

Answer (score 0):

You can add transaction controller
Thread > Add > Login Controllers > Transaction Controller
and can copy the useful url.